# Angular 2, routerOnActivate method is never called for a component that implements OnActivate

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to log the current route using Angular 2 Router, using the sample code from the official documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/OnActivate-interface.html

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {
    OnActivate,
    ComponentInstruction
} from 'angular2/router';


@Component({selector: 'header-title', template: `<div>routerOnActivate: {{log}}</div>`})
export class HeaderTitle implements OnActivate {
    log: string = '';

    routerOnActivate(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) {
        console.log('hello on activate');
        this.log = `Finished navigating from "${prev ? prev.urlPath : 'null'}" to "${next.urlPath}"`;
    }
}
```

The method `routerOnActivate` is never called.

I configured the routes using the `RouteConfig` annotation:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', component: Home, name: 'Index', data: {title: 'Index page'}},
    {path: '/home', component: Home, name: 'Home', data: {title: 'Welcome Home'}},
    {path: '/**', redirectTo: ['Index']}
])
```

Is there something else that I should configure in the Router to activate listeners ?

Comment: The `implement` part is not important here. Is `HeaderTitle` loaded through routing? Otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: @EricMartinez you mean I should load it in a route like the Home component `{path: '/', component: Home, name: 'Index', data: {title: 'Index page'}}`? It is currently loaded through a directive `<header-title></header-title>` contained in the Home component's template.

Comment: Yes, @gpereira exactly. The `implement` part is just for helping you with typings so the IDE doesn't complain. To be sure add a `routerOnActivaite` in your `Home` component and see if it is called at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to implement the routerOnActivate method inside a component that resolves the path. In your example it'll be called if you implement it in the Home Component.